# How do I change cursor to pointer when mouse is over a node

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am new to Cytoscape.js. I've managed to create a network. I'd like to change mouse cursor to pointer when mouse is over a node. Based on what I read, I should use the following code:

```
style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .css({
          'content': 'data(name)',
          'text-valign': 'center',
          'color': 'white',
          'text-outline-width': 2,
          'text-outline-color': '#888',          
          'cursor': 'pointer'
       })

//other code omitted
```

To my surprise, the cursor did not change. It stayed the same default cursor. What did I miss? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
This worked for me :

cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function (evt) {                            
                        $('html,body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    } );

cy.on('mouseout', 'node', function (evt) {
                        $('html,body').css('cursor', 'default');
                    });
```

Comment: This works but is a bit unreliable, if `mouseout` event fails to fire (happens easily in my quick test) then the cursor stays as a hand over the rest of your webpage until you go over another node and successfully get the end to fire when leaving the node.

Answer (score 3):

Due to technical issues with the cursor across browsers and the fact that the cursor does not apply at all on touch devices, Cy.js no longer supports the `cursor` property.

Comment: Terrific! We need this.

Answer (score 2):

Put a helper class on the wrapper DOM element or on the canvas itself using cytoscape events:

```
cys.on('mouseover', 'node', () => $(targetElement).addClass('mouseover'));
cys.on('mouseout', 'node', () => $(targetElement).removeClass('mouseover'));
```

Then in css:
`.cysWrapper.mouseover { cursor: pointer; }`

Answer (score 2):

```
cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function(e){
    $('#diagram-wrapper').css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
cy.on('mouseout', 'node', function(e){
    $('#diagram-wrapper').css('cursor', 'default');
});
```

`diagram-wrapper` is a div containing the cytoscape.js diagram.

`cy` is the cytoscape js object

This code is inside `$(document).ready(function() {...}` along with the declaration of `cy`.

---

Thanks to the other answers for inspiration. I couldn't quite get them to behave so this the hybrid that I ended up with